# Is the assumption of independence between the error terms of a predictive regression with non-stationary or highly persistent regressors unreasonable?

Tags: predictive-models, independence, stationarity, predictor

Let us define a predictive regression as follows
\begin{equation}
y_t=\beta x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t,\quad\text{for}\quad t=1,\cdots,n
\end{equation}
where $y_t$ is usually very noisy (and stationary - i.e. $I(0)$), while $x_{t-1}$ is either non-stationary ($I(1)$) or the autoregressive parameter $\rho$ in
\begin{equation}
x_t=\rho x_{t-1}+u_t,
\end{equation}
is local-to-unity - i.e.
\begin{equation}
\rho\approx1+c/n
\end{equation}
for some small constant $c$. In such circumstances, is it reasonable to assume that $\{\varepsilon_t\}_{t=1}^n$ are independent? Or would this be a strong assumption?

Comment: If $y_t$ is I(0) and $x_{t-1}$ is I(1) then $\varepsilon_t$ must be I(1) and thus definitely not independent.

Comment: Ahhh of course! you are correct.